# How to Boost a Field In Lucene.Net 3

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, lucene.net

I want to boost a field in Lucene.Net 3.0.3. However the SetBoost Method doesnt appear to be defined anymore in Lucene. How do I boost a field, say, I want the "Title" of a document to carry more weight that the rest of the fields?

Comment: In Lucene.Net 3, proper properties were introduced to replace the Set_ and Get_ methods. So you'll now see a Boost property instead of SetBoost() and GetBoost() methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can boost a field in index time or in search time.
To boost a field in index time you can set:

```
 Field titleField = new Field("title", strTitle, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
 titleField.Boost = 2;

 doc.Add(titleField);
```

remember that OmitNorms must be set to false.

To boost a field in search time you can set:

```
  TermQuery q = new TermQuery(new Term("title", "cat"));
  q.Boost = 2;

  _searcher.Search(q, 100);
```